# Synchronise claws-mail instances

Tags: email, mail-user-agent

I run claws-mail on multiple computers and would like to synchronise the configuration and address books. Is there some canonical way to do this? I couldn’t find instructions in the manual and I don't want to sync the whole `~/.claws-mail` folder if possible.